# How to scroll left and right in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I use PhpStorm 7.1 on a Windows 7 notebook.
Scrolling up and down in a fileview with my **touchpad** works, scrolling left and right doesn't work. There is no issue with my touchpad, because I can scroll left and right in other editors like Notepad++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow [IDEA-115509](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115509) for updates